# Getting similar posts by custom field value

Tags: plugin-development

I have several custom fields for my posts, one of them is called nearby, its role is to store cities that are close by. So let's say I have a supermarket called Janny's and its custom field for **Near by has: New York, New Jersey, Las Vegas**
I want to use the first value (in this example **New York**) and show posts that also contain that . The problem is that the query is something like this:

```
$value="New York";
$postss = new WP_Query([
                'post_type'      => 'post',
                'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'meta_key'       => 'Near by:',
                'meta_value'     => $value,
                'meta_compare'   => 'LIKE',
]);
```

This is working, except it doesn't just show posts that contain **New York** as first (meaning closest city) but also if they are far away, for example:

Store name: Jony's
**Near by: New Mexico, Los Angeles, New York**
in this example New York is not the first city (meaning closest to the store) so it would be better if we just show posts that have New York in first position.

I was wondering if you can help me out how to compare just the first value of current post, with the first value of other posts.

Answer (score 1):

To compare just the first value of the "Near by" custom field for your current post with the first value of the "Near by" custom field for other posts, you can use the "SUBSTRING_INDEX" function in your meta query.

Here's an example of how you can modify your WP_Query to only show posts that have the same first value as your current post:

```
$current_nearby = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Near by', true );
$current_nearby_first = strtok( $current_nearby, ',' ); // Get the first nearby city

$postss = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'post__not_in'   => array( $post->ID ),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'Near by',
            'value'   => $current_nearby_first,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'type'    => 'CHAR', // Ensure case-sensitive comparison
            'where'   => 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(meta_value, ",", 1) = SUBSTRING_INDEX("' . $current_nearby . '", ",", 1)', // Compare only the first nearby city
        ),
    ),
]);
```

Note that this solution assumes that nearby cities are separated by commas in the "Near by" custom field. If your nearby cities are separated by something else, you'll need to adjust the where parameter accordingly.